# Java8 metaspace & heap usage

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, jvm-hotspot, metaspace

I have this code to generate class dynamically and load it

```
import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;

public class PermGenLeak {
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.jigarjoshi.permgenleak.";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CannotCompileException, InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            pool.makeClass(PACKAGE_NAME + i).toClass();
            Thread.sleep(3);
        }

    }
}
```

I launched this class against Java 7 (jdk1.7.0_60) and as expected it filled up PermGenSpace and heap remained unused [image: Java 7 memory usage]
<sub>image shows permgen usage overtime and at the end JVM was terminated</sub>

Now the same code ran against Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_40-ea) and as expected it kept expanding native memory (Metaspace) but surprisingly for 1g of Metaspace it consumed 3g of Heap in OldGen (almost 3x of Metaspace maintained over time)

[image: Java8 memory usage]
<sub>image shows Metaspace  usage overtime and System memory usage sample</sub>

[this email from Jon Masamitsu](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2012-September/006679.html) and [this JEP ticket](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122) says

> interned `String` and Class stats and some misc data has been moved to Heap

what exactly makes this increase in heap as it loads more classes into Metaspace ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run `jmap -histo PID` to see which objects consume the Heap Space.
When I ran your example I saw the heap full of Javassist auxiliary objects:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:        592309      312739152  [Ljavassist.bytecode.ConstInfo;
   2:       6515673      208501536  java.util.HashMap$Node
   3:       2964403      169188824  [C
   4:       1777622      102165184  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   5:       4146200       99508800  javassist.bytecode.Utf8Info
   6:       3553889       85293336  java.util.ArrayList
   7:       2964371       71144904  java.lang.String
   8:        593075       56944008  java.lang.Class
   9:        592332       47388032  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
  10:        592309       37907776  javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
  11:        592308       37907712  javassist.CtNewClass
  12:       1185118       28555808  [B
  13:        592342       28432416  java.util.HashMap
  14:       1184624       28430976  javassist.bytecode.ClassInfo
  15:        592309       28430832  [[Ljavassist.bytecode.ConstInfo;
  16:        592322       23692880  javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo
  17:        592315       23692600  javassist.bytecode.CodeAttribute
  18:        592434       18957888  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  19:        592309       18953888  javassist.bytecode.ConstPool
  20:        592308       18953856  java.lang.ref.WeakReference
  21:        592318       14215632  javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo
  22:        592318       14215632  javassist.bytecode.NameAndTypeInfo
  23:        592315       14215560  javassist.bytecode.ExceptionTable
  24:        592309       14215416  javassist.bytecode.LongVector
  25:        592309       14215416  javassist.bytecode.SourceFileAttribute
  26:        592507        9487584  [I
  27:             8        6292528  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
  28:           212          18656  java.lang.reflect.Method
  29:           407          13024  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
  30:           124           8928  java.lang.reflect.Field
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I should have just executed this, I think I didn't reach at this scale in Java 7 example that is why I didn't see it in Java 7

Answer (score 3):

> what exactly makes this increase in heap as it loads more classes into Metaspace ?

My hypothesis is that this is "ordinary" garbage that is being created by your example.  I surmise that:

- The `javaassist` code creates regular heap objects.  They are mostly "big" and that causes them to be allocated directly into the OldGen heap.  Or something else causes that.

  (**UPDATE** - looking at @apangin's Answer, I now suspect that they started out in the YoungGen heap and were tenured ...)
- When `classLoader.defineClass` is called under the hood, it creates objects in metaspace from the byte array containing the classfile.
- The OldGen usage remains ... because nothing has triggered a full GC yet.

If you tweaked your example so that the classes were reachable, and then forced a full GC, I would expect (hope) to see the OldHeap usage to drop, indicating that it is "ordinary" garbage rather than a storage leak.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, It totally make sense now, I think I didn't reach at this scale of allocation in Java 7 example that is why I didn't see it in Java 7

Comment: can you please include code to demonstrate your solution